# Magnetic Acceleration due to Repulsion

Tags: acceleration

My question concerns magnetic acceleration due to repulsion. My sketch below shows two Neodymium magnets that I am working with, **Magnet A** and **Magnet B**. Thir orientation is fixed so that they cannot twist, and they are confined to travel only in the direction of the arrows. My questions are:

1. If **Magnet A** is at rest and **Magnet B** is moved towards it from left to right in the direction of the arrow, how could I determine how fast **Magnet A** would accelerate away from **B**?
2. I suspect that the speed at which **Magnet B** is traveling would affect the acceleration of **Magnet A**. So, would it be possible to determine how this speed would influence the acceleration of **Magnet A**

***If it is not possible to provide answers in this forum, I would be very grateful if someone could provide information (books, videos etc) on where I could get help***.

Thanks very much.

[image]

Comment: The magnetic fields of finite-sized magnets are complicated close to the magnets. I recommend thinking about two [point magnetic dipoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole), which have relatively simple fields and simple forces. This simplification should still capture what would happen in the finite case.

Comment: I would recommend starting a search with Wikipedia.  Their page on [Force between magnets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Force_between_two_bar_magnets) should have everything.  If not, please edit the question to capture what you think is missing from that page to solve your particular problem.

Comment: (For future reference, I found that link by taking your question title, adding "wikipedia" to it, and thus googling for "Magnetic Acceleration due to Repulsion wikipedia".)

Comment: *I suspect that the speed at which Magnet B is traveling would affect the acceleration of Magnet A.* Why? I think the magnets would have to be moving at a significant fraction of the speed of light for this to be significant.